# Internationalization i18n message to model for web application with jsf2

Tags: jsf, model, internationalization

I have an application JEE with jsf2 and my application model have a result of the operation with a message.

an example with code my model class

```
/*
 * This code is under license Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 1.0
 * <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/1.0/legalcode"></a>
 */
package it.unibas.printspooler.modello.logic.state;

import it.unibas.printspooler.Costanti;
import it.unibas.printspooler.modello.operations.Operation;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo
 */
public class FreeState extends AbstractSpoolerState {

    private final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(FreeState.class);

    public FreeState() {
        super(Costanti.State.STATE_FREE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBusy() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isError() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFree() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescriptionState() {
        return super.getState();
    }

    @Override
    public String hasPrintable(PrintSpoiler spoller, Operation newOperation, Operation lastOperation) {
        super.hasPrintable(spoller, newOperation, lastOperation);

        if(spoller.getWaitOperation().isEmpty()){
            LOGGER.debug("The wait queue operation is empty");
            spoller.getSuccessulfuOperation().add(newOperation);
            return "The wait queue operation is empty";
        }

        return "The wait queue operation isn't empty, the spooler state is busy";
    }


}
```

The method that returns the message into screen.jsf is

```
@Override
    public String hasPrintable(PrintSpoiler spoller, Operation newOperation, Operation lastOperation) {
        super.hasPrintable(spoller, newOperation, lastOperation);

        if(spoller.getWaitOperation().isEmpty()){
            LOGGER.debug("The wait queue operation is empty");
            spoller.getSuccessulfuOperation().add(newOperation);
            return "The wait queue operation is empty";
        }

        return "The wait queue operation isn't empty, the spooler state is busy";
    }
```

I should internationalization this message with the framework jsf2

- return "The wait queue operation isn't empty, the spooler state is busy";
- return "The wait queue operation is empty";

Sorry my terrible English but I'm learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ressource bundle to i18n your labels. It's possible to use a bundle directly from your xhtml pages and/or in your Java beans.

A lot of websites presents this techniques with a lot of details, personally I'd start with those two :

1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_internationalization.htm
2. https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/